# How to show widget from parent screen without rebuilding after Navigator.push

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to use [focused_menu](https://pub.dev/packages/focused_menu) plugin to achieve the following functionality [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Sn1V.png)

When I wrap the images - everything works perfect, but when I try to wrap video instead - it reloads every time the item is clicked. I suppose key problem is that focused_menu navigates to a new screen using Navigator.push and place wrapped widget on this screen. But at the save time [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) plugin initialize its controller in initState method:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });
  }
```

So the value of

```
_controller.value.isInitialized
```

is false.

Is it possible to persist widget on the new screen, so that it will not be rebuilding after Navigator.push?

Answer (score 0):

Passing the widget in arguments while making it const will prevent it building again.

Comment: It doesn't work because video urls can't have const values in my case